# shortcut for 'update to HEAD'

Tags: eclipse, svn, keyboard-shortcuts

is there any way to have either

- **shortcut** or
- **icon**

for svn `Update to HEAD` of one project (not all of them) in eclipse? It would make my life much much easier.

I have few php projects though. Time to time I click 'commit' by accident.

Running Eclipse for PHP Developers - Helios release - on OS X.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm posting this to help anyone interested since I got a lot of grief before figuring this out..

You have to go to Settings > General > Keys and bind the shortcuts as the others have said.

I have:

- Commit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- Update to HEAD: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>
- Synchronize with Repository: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, all "In Windows"

But, in order for the shortcuts to work, you must go to Window dropdown menu > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability and there check the SVN box.

With this option you also get a dropdown menu called SVN with all the relevant commands.

Selecting the file/package/project/working set and pressing the keys does its magic.

Answer (score 3):

In preferences go to Bindings

Sort by category

Find SVN

Assign a shortcut to "Update"

Mine is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Comment: I did so and it does nothing. what is your `when`? Mine `In Windows`. I want to update the whole project. I have few projects though.

Answer (score 2):

Go to preferences and type "Bindings" in the search at the top and play around with that. You can't bind a button to it, but you might be able to bind a key to do what you want.

Comment: I didn't find anything I could use :-(