# Eclipse Shortcut for Team - Synchronize with Repository

Tags: eclipse

What are the shortcuts for the context menu actions "Team -> Synchronize with Repository" and "Team -> Update" on the whole project?

I have already found shortcuts, but these are executed only on the file i have currently opened. But I want to execute it on the whole project without having to scroll the project explorer to the top and right-clicking on the project.

If there are no such shortcuts, how can I create them?

Answer (score 7):

As john.k.doe indicates, that's the right solution, but you also need to do something else in order to make the shortcut actually work, which is go to Window > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability and there just check the SVN box ;)

Answer (score 6):

you can almost always get the key shortcuts you want by

1. go to preferences type "keys" or go to General -> Keys
2. in the field presented when you click on "Keys"
3. in the left pane, type the command you are interested in setting up a shortcut for:

the image below is from my mac, but it works the same way on windows/linux, you just might choose something besides Cmd-Y as your shortcut modifier.  the U under User indicates that i was the one to add that modification.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this only invokes Synchronize on the current selection, with the question clearly states is not the desired result.

Comment: because the question clearly stated they didn't want the current selection, before i posted it, i tried it out and it definitely worked for me in any 'In Windows' context, not just on the current selection.  thanks for knocking it down a point, though.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? When I invoke this command in Eclipse Indigo (3.7.x) via keyboard, it only synchronizes the selection (file, folder, package, project, whatever). I tried in Java, Resources, and Java Browsing perspectives.

Answer (score 5):

I have written a small Eclipse plug-in which selects the active project in the Package Explorer so you can execute other actions (like 'Sync with repo' and 'Update') on it. I think this approach is more flexible compared to writing a plug-in that selects the project and executes a predefined action.

You can get the plug-in at http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/eclipse-tweaks/downloads/list, it is named "com.xakcop.select". Download it and put it in the dropins/ folder of your Eclipse installation. Then when you restart Eclipse, you will find a new command `Select project` in `Windows->Preferences->Keys`. The default key binding is `Ctrl+Shift+Backspace` but you can change it to whatever you want.

When you are in the Java editor just press `Ctrl+Shift+Backspace`, this will select the project that the current file belongs to in Package Explorer. Then press the shortcut for "Synchronize with repository" and you are done.

The source code of the plug-in is also available as part of my *eclipse-tweaks* project: http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/eclipse-tweaks/source/browse/com.xakcop.select

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604999/shortcut-for-update-to-head/6927759#6927759) adresses the issue.

The quickest way I've found to update/synchronize, after having set the shortcut keys, is to click on the minimize button in the Project/Package Explorer and then press the keys. After the update, simply clicking on the last used file in the editor returns to the previous workspace state (provided the "Link with Editor" button in Project Explorer is selected).

I should clarify: I use a working set for each project. The working sets are displayed as default Top Level Elements in the Package Explorer so, by clicking on the minimize button the desired Project' working set, they collapse and are easy to select. *Then*, I apply the shortcut on the selected working set.

Comment: The question is looking for a way to synchronize the entire project, regardless of what file is selected or open. I don't see how this method will first select the Project before invoking Synchronize.

Comment: E-Riz you are right, I had not explained it enough. I hope now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the problem is the focus of the commands you execute.
The Team commands Snychronize and Update are executed on the current object (In my case). As you noticed, when you execute the command on the project, the project is synchonized - when you do it on a file, only the file is synchronized.

What I did as workaround is the following:
I created Key-Bindings for the commands *Show in (Navigator)* (Alt-N), *Go to* (Alt-G), and *Show View (Naviator)* (CTRL+SHIFT+Q, N).
With Alt-N I show the current File in the Navigator. I can then use the keys to navigate to the root that I want to synchronize (it's not always the whole project for me). If the root is to far away I use Alt-G and type the Project or Folder where I want to go to and execute afterwards the Synchronize commands. 
(Go to works only in the current view)

If you have selected the Project once you just have to switch to the navigator (Show View command) and execute your synchronize commands.

You could also use rgerganov's plugin then you would not have to execute as many commands.
The procedure works also with other views (package explorer, project explorer)

What about this approach? It should also work for other SCM's or commands you want to execute on any object in the explorer views.