# Open Resource Shortcut doesnt Work

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

the shortcut for "Open Resource"(Ctlr+Shift+R) does not work in my eclipse (Version 4.8.0).
Instead of open the search window theres just a "no matches" box in the bottom right corner ([no matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbiqx.png)).

I tried the shortcut in the perspectives Java, Java EE, Debug, Javascript; same behavior as descripted above.

The shortcut is assigned to Open Resource under General->Keys ([Key assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqGVN.png))
I also added the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + Ä, which works fine, but Ctrl + Shift + R does not. There are no conflicts showed.

Under Navigate->Open Resource the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + R is shown.

Additionally, some other own shortcuts do not work (e.g. shortcuts for Update-to-Head (SVN), Commit(SVN)), but others do (e.g. Open "About" Window).
Earlier on I changed the shortcut for Open Resource to test the functionality of own shortcuts, but I restored the defaults after that.

In configuration/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/setup.log following action is executed:

```
Performing Preference /instance/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.commands = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...
[2018-08-15 11:35:26] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<org.eclipse.ui.commands>
<keyBinding commandId="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.commit" contextId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorScope"
keyConfigurationId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"keySequence="CTRL+SHIFT+Ä"/>
<keyBinding contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window" keyConfigurationId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" keySequence="CTRL+SHIFT+R"/>
<keyBinding commandId="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui.commit" contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window" keyConfigurationId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" keySequence="CTRL+SHIFT+C"/> 
<keyBinding commandId="org.eclipse.ui.navigate.openResource" contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"keyConfigurationId="org.eclipse.ui defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" keySequence="CTRL+SHIFT+R CTRL+SHIFT+L"/>
```

How do i change these startup tasks?

I would appreciate any kind of Help.
Best Regards,
Bernd

Comment: The Ctrl+Alt+R _Open Resource_ shortcut might be overridden by a command with the same shortcut but a more specific scope than _Window_ (_When_ = _In Windows_). Does Ctlr+Alt+R open the _Open Resource_ dialog if a view (e. g. the _Package Explorer_ or the _Console_ view) is focused? Ctrl+Shift+L shows all active shortcuts within the current scope: Which command does it show for Ctrl+Alt+R? In the _Keys_ preference dialog you can also filter for `Ctrl+Alt+R`.

Comment: When i sort the Key list by Key Bindings, Ctlr+Shift+R is the only used by Open Resource. Changing the view or perspective doesnt change the outcome. Ctrl+Shift+R is bind to Open Resource in active shortcuts within the current scope, double click opens it, but pressing Ctrl+Shift+R again only delivers the "No matches" as showed in the picture.

Comment: In your question you talk about Ctrl + **Alt** + R, but in the screenshot and by default the shortcut is Ctrl + **Shift** + R. Every widget can consume a keystroke. Please try to set the focus into different views and editors: is the behavior always the same (I guess it isn't). Please try also to hit Ctrl+Shift+L and look which command is shown in this dialog for Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: Im sorry, that is my bad, I meant Ctrl+Shift+R in all cases. I just want the standard configuration (after using the "Restore Default" action the shortcut still does not work). I will try the different perspectives. When i restore defaults and restart eclipse, there is a short time when i can use Ctrl+Shift+R to open Resource. Apparently there is a startup task which change the keybindings, but i dont know where to configure startup tasks

Comment: Startup tasks: _Window > Preferences: Oomph > Setup Task_ (and _General > Startup and Shutdown_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a startup task under C:\Users\USER\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.setup\setups\user.setup which changed the keybinding. 
I have no clue why a manual change back to the old keybinding did not work, but i am happy that it works now.

> Additionally, some other own shortcuts do not work (e.g. shortcuts for Update-to-Head (SVN), Commit(SVN)), but others do (e.g. Open "About" Window). Earlier on I changed the shortcut for Open Resource to test the functionality of own shortcuts, but I restored the defaults after that.

For my this problem I found this question [shortcut for 'update to HEAD'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604999/shortcut-for-update-to-head) which solves it. 
Thank You for your help 
Sincerely 
Naphthali